# How track all data changes on a database

Tags: sql-server

I have received a new database for an **ETL** application on SQL Server 2017.

But I need to know if in this database the ETL software inserts **GDPR-  relevant data** or not.

My first thought was to use the SQL Server Profiler to watch what kind of data the application inserts.

But what if the application inserts data like this?

```
SELECT *  
INTO [DBO].[TABLENAME]  
FROM OPENQUERY (OTHERDB, 'SELECT * FROM SourceTable')
```

Or the application uses bulk copy operations to insert data into the database?
Or maybe it exists an other possibility where an ETL applications can insert data, that I cannot see with the profiler?

Can someone answer: where is the problem, query afterwards all tables...

But, what is if the application caches only the data in this database and immediately deletes it?

I know, I can use Wireshark to sniff the network traffic to achieve my goal, but what is, if the network traffic is encrypted with SSL?

Maybe I think too complicated, but if someone can clarify my doubts, help is appreciated...

An valuable answer can be: "Don't worry, with profiler you get all data inserts/changes" **or** "You are right, with Profiler you can not get all data inserts/changes because... .   I consider to you to use ...-tool/method to achive your goal"

Comment: Do you know the target of these insertions (ie specific table.column it would go into) if not then how would you know that this is some GDPR sensitive data? What do you want to do with it once you get this knowledge? Mask it? Encrypt it? Delete? Alert on it?

Comment: Hi Bartosz, no, i don't know nothing about the tables, there are more thousands of tables in this DB. If the DB contains GDPR relevant data i say to the customer to use an other DBMS, because with other requirements of this ETL-application i cannot be GDPR compatible on MS SQL - Server...

Comment: Profiler traces are definitely *not* a reliable way to capture all data, because the server may drop events if they cannot be processed quickly enough. That can be "fixed" by using extended events and the `NO_EVENT_LOSS` session option, but that still wouldn't change the fact that you can't use events to capture all data. Your best bet for that is the transaction log itself, under full recovery mode. This allows point-in-time recovery on (a copy of) the database. There are also third-party tools that offer to read the transaction log, but I have no experience with those.

Comment: Can you please add more context? It is impossible to determine if data are GDPR relevant or not just by watching the data. If you want to comply, **everything** is about documentation.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen! Maybe i can see the data in TLOG, i must try it. Very good to know, that with Profiler is not possible to get all data inserts/updates!

Comment: Hi Homer, your are right, but i have no possibilitys to ask the company that produces the ETL-application (its a very big one, that lets pay a lot for answering this kind of questions...). My goal is to understand, if we can implement this application (the application needs sysadmin-rights!) or not on SQL-Server...

Comment: I am sorry, but it looks like you want a real time transaction log analysis in the background with some advanced AI to determinate is a bit of data concerned as GDPR relevant or not. I have never heard about such a tool and you won't find it in the SQL Server for sure.

Comment: Hi Bartosz, a "transaction log"-analyzer can be helpfull, yes. But not a "advanced AI" - thing, because i know the data, that the ETL - tool elaborates. Knowing the data, i need only to watch if this data would be stored in the database or if the ETL-Server elaborates all of this data in RAM...

Answer (score 0):

You could look at implementing SQL Server's change data capture feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Froger: Why not? Why does the number of tables matter? If the issue is the number of statements necessary to enable CDC on all of them, that's a simple matter of automation: write a query to generate those statements.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, mmmh, ok with scripting its possible. I hoped that it exists a more elegant and simpler way, because its a important project where the management makes pressure and i don't want cause problems with doing changes on the DB that can cause maybe troubles on the entire project...